# Helper class for text that will go on a dark background

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In my first Bootstrap project, I'm putting some text on a dark background, so I need the text to be light-colored so it will show up. I can just set `color: white` on the text, but the text has links in it, which means I need to go set the color for those too.

Does Bootstrap have a helper class to do this for me? I only ask because it has [six different helper classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-colors) for changing text and links to various colors, and it seems strange that there's no fast and easy solution for text that goes onto a photo or other dark background.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why would you not want to roll your own helper class?

Comment: Not really, I'm just trying to learn Bootstrap's way of doing things. Bootstrap seems to have pre-built helper classes for an astonishing number of scenarios. It seems like "light text on a dark background" should be common enough that I would expect Bootstrap to have an easy way of doing that. I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally use those classes on your link as in:

```
<a class="text-danger">things</a>
```

If you open up bootstrap.css and search for .text-danger you'll find that the css is merely assigning a color:

```
    .text-danger {
  color: #b94a48;
}
```

You could also make your own class:

```
<a class="stuffandjunk">things</a>
```

Then in your css:

```
    .stuffandjunk {
    color: #428bca;
}
```

In addition you'd probably want to make styles for hover and active for your new class, check out the documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)